# How do you get only dictionary items from JSON in python?

Tags: python, json

I'm on python 3.8. Here an example JSON file i'm working with:

```json
{
  "dict1": {
      "text": "here",
      "more text": "here too"
      },
  "dict2": {
      "cool": "text",
      "filler": "element"
      }
}
```

I'm eventually gonna be working with multiple dicts and won't always know the names of them. When I do this:

```py
import json

with open("jsonfile.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
for element in data:
    if element is dict:
        print(element)
```

It prints nothing. No error messages, just nothing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to debug this yourself. Start by printing ‘element’ every time.

Comment: `data` is a dictionary. Looping over a dictionary returns the keys, not the values.

Comment: And `is` does not check the type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to iterate the values of a dictionary, use `dict.values()`

```
d = {
  "dict1": {
      "text": "here",
      "more text": "here too"
      },
  "dict2": {
      "cool": "text",
      "filler": "element"
      }
}

for element in d.values():
    if type(element) == dict:
        print(element)
```

```
{'text': 'here', 'more text': 'here too'}
{'cool': 'text', 'filler': 'element'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json

with open("jsonfile.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
for element in data.values():
    if isinstance(element, dict):
        print(element)
```